# Install bluetooth driver in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth

I have a dual-boot system of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 (AsusX55C)
I want to install bluetooth drivers on my pc in Ubuntu and there are drivers that are supported only for Windows 8 according to my pc ,so I have heard that we can install Windows drivers in Ubuntu so how to do that?
And the most important thing that the drivers are not manual they have to installed through the installer that the manufacrurer provide so how can I run that installer in Ubuntu.
Thankyou.

Output for command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` is

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2883 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2717:ff40 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (MTP)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: You should not need to install any drivers they are in the kernel.

Comment: What is the real problem? Does Bluetooth work?

Comment: No bluetooth is not detected in settings @Pilot6

Comment: How to install drivers in kernal? @David

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` command.

Comment: Yeah I have done it.@Pilot6

Comment: I am afraid there is no easy solution for this Ralink device.

Comment: You can't install Windows drivers, and there are no working Linux drivers.

Comment: So can I find and install driver manually @Pilot6

Comment: You can if you find one. But the problem is that there is no driver for current sustems for this old device.

Comment: By the way thanks for you quick response @Pilot6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the latest driver from github by using gdebi package installer and using this command :- `sudo modprobe rtbth`  now its working but not finding any device :( .

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms

sudo apt update

sudo apt install rtbth-dkms

sudo vim /etc/rc.local
```

Add the command `modprobe rtbth &> /dev/null` right before "exit 0" and save.

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/rc.local
sudo apt install blueman
```

Reboot.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
systemctl start bluetooth
sudo modprobe btusb 
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Comment: I tried installing and trying blueman commands and installed its application but after I ran it displayed that the device has no adapter

Comment: Output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: Output of the command       ``` 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no```

Comment: Yes Done. @Edmund

Comment: `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install dkms`

Comment: Done should I restart? @Edmund.

Comment: After sudo apt update terminal said that 4 ubdates are upgradable and I saw them but didn't said that how to install them? @Edmund

Comment: `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: No bluetooth found :( @Edmund

Comment: yes it's work for me in Ubuntu-20.04 LTS with kernam 5.12.0-051200-generic
I also have run `sudo apt install -f`