# asus-rog ubuntu 20.04 no turn on button of bluetooth

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, asus

I want to use bluetooth mouse on my ASUS-ROG-M16 laptop, but I met some trouble with the bluetooth. I searched a lot and no one solved my problem, this is my first problem in `Ask Ubuntu`. I haved wasted a lot of time and I was very frustrated.

The problem is that there is no `turn on` button of my bluetooth settings?

[Screenshot: no `turn on` button of bluetooth settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15g82.png)

[The bluetooth settings GUI looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X22Yl.png)

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl scan on
No default controller available
```

```
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-04-22 00:48:44 CST; 12min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 845 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 47676)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─845 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 22 00:48:44 ROG systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Apr 22 00:48:44 ROG bluetoothd[845]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Apr 22 00:48:44 ROG systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 22 00:48:44 ROG bluetoothd[845]: Starting SDP server
Apr 22 00:48:44 ROG bluetoothd[845]: Bluetooth management interface 1.20 initialized
```

```
$ rfkill list
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    2.483004] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.483018] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.483020] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.483022] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.483023] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.636864] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.636866] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    2.636870] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.958425] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
[    8.958429] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x0, device=0x0
[    8.958431] Bluetooth: DynamicAlloc pci_device_id table at 0x00000000e812b2d1 with size 64
[    8.958434] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
[    8.958435] Bluetooth: Convert: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
[    8.958436] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x0, device=0x0
[    8.958438] Bluetooth: pci_device_id: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 27c6:521d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:5458 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0b05:19b6 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I found in other threads that `sudo rmmod btusb` and `sudo modprobe btusb` or others [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304427/install-bluetooth-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04) should help, but for me it did not.

Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: If you want any more information, please feel free to send an email to me: lebronlihd@gmail.com, thank you!!!!!

Comment: Same problem with my ROG G15 2022. Wifi works ok, but bluetooth is same like yours. I have tried linuxmint20.3+kernel5.15.35，ubuntu22.04+kernel5.17.4, still cannot fix it. Maybe the mt7922 module is too new. I will try other latest distro later, such as Fedora 36 Beta.

Comment: @LeBronHDLi, you've tried installing bluez/Blueman? You can give it a shot @  [link](https://techsphinx.com/linux/install-blueman-ubuntu/)